# Vuejs Array update with new value not working as expected

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This is the template code for survey builder I am receiving the proper response from the server. The value of addAnotherQuestion is not updating properly. I also tried other ways but with no luck. Your help will be appreciated.

```
   <div v-for="(addItem, addItemIndex) in addAnotherQuestion" :key="addItemIndex">
     {{addItem.question}}
     {{addItem.options}}
   </div>
```

this is default value

```
data() {
    return {
       addAnotherQuestion: [
        {
          id: 1,
          enableSingle: false,
          enableMultiple: false,
          enableLong: false,
          enableScale: false,
          enableMatrix: false,
          enableMatrixMulti: false,
          enablePlain: false,
          type: "single",
          // options: ["", ""],
          question_number: 1,
          disableOption: true,
          question: "",
          required: true,
          hasOther: false,
          isOpen: false,
          scale: '0',
          rows: [
            {
              label : "ROW 1",
              id : 1
            },
            {
              label : "ROW 2",
              id : 2
            },
          ],
          columns: [
            {
              label : "COL 1",
              id : 1
            },
            {
              label : "COL 2",
              id : 2
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    }
```

```
mounted(){
this.getSurveyQuestion();
}
computed:{ ...mapGettersSurvey(["questionList"])},
methods:{
...mapActionsSurvey(["GET_SURVEY_QUESTION"]),
getSurveyQuestion() {
      let params = { id: this.surveyId };
      let isDetailsFound=false;
      this.GET_SURVEY_QUESTION(params).then((result) => {
        console.log('result', result)
        if (result) {
          //this is just a response from server not a code
          [
            {
            "id": 1,
            "question": "Test question -1",
            "question_number": 1,
            "options": [
                   "Option 1",
                   "Option 2",
                   "Option 3"
                      ],
             "required": true,
             "hasOther": false,
             "type": "single"
             },
             {
             "id": 2,
             "question": "Test Question -2",
             "question_number": 2,
             "options": [
                   "Option -1",
                   "Option -2"
              ],
              "required": true,
              "hasOther": false,
              "type": "multiple_choice"
              }
              ]
          //response over--this response is from server
          let details = this.questionList;
          if (details.length > 0) {
            isDetailsFound = true;
            for (let i = 0; i < details.length; i++) {
              if (details[i].type === "single") {
                details[i].enableSingle = true;
              } else if (details[i].type === "multiple_choice") {
                details[i].enableMultiple = true;
              } else if (details[i].type === "open_text") {
                details[i].enableLong = true;
              } else if (details[i].type === "distribution_scale") {
                details[i].enableScale = true;
              } else if (details[i].type === "single_variant") {
                details[i].enableMatrix = true;
              } else if (details[i].type === "multiple_variant") {
                details[i].enableMatrixMulti = true;
              } else if (details[i].type === "plain_text_number") {
                details[i].enablePlain = true;                
              }
            }

            this.addAnotherQuestion = details;
          }
        }
        if(!isDetailsFound){
          this.addAnotherQuestion[0].enableSingle = true;
        }
      });
    }
}
```

Here the options are not getting changed
[image]

I dont know where am I doing wrong.
I also tried this :

```
if (details.length > 0) {                       
            let temp = this.addAnotherQuestion[0];
            let addAnotherQuestion2 = [];   
            console.log('addQ',this.addAnotherQuestion);
            isDetailsFound = true;
            for (let i = 0; i < details.length; i++) {
              let resultQuestion = temp; 
              console.log('temp',temp);             
              if (details[i].type === "single") {
                resultQuestion.id = details[i].id;
                resultQuestion.question_number = details[i].question_number
                resultQuestion.enableSingle = true;
                console.log(details[i].question);
                resultQuestion.question = details[i].question;
                resultQuestion.options = details[i].options;
                resultQuestion.type = details[i].type;
                resultQuestion.enableMultiple = false;
                resultQuestion.enableLong = false;
                resultQuestion.enableScale = false;
                resultQuestion.enableMatrix = false;
                resultQuestion.enableMatrixMulti = false;
                resultQuestion.enablePlain = false;   
                resultQuestion.disableOption = true,          
                resultQuestion.required = details[i].required;
                resultQuestion.hasOther = details[i].hasOther;                
                resultQuestion.isOpen = false;
                addAnotherQuestion2.push(resultQuestion);     
              } else if (details[i].type === "multiple_choice") { 
                resultQuestion.id = details[i].id;
                resultQuestion.question_number = details[i].question_number
                resultQuestion.enableSingle = false;
                resultQuestion.question = details[i].question;
                console.log(details[i].question);
                resultQuestion.options = details[i].options;
                resultQuestion.type = details[i].type;
                resultQuestion.enableMultiple = true;
                resultQuestion.enableLong = false;
                resultQuestion.enableScale = false;
                resultQuestion.enableMatrix = false;
                resultQuestion.enableMatrixMulti = false;
                resultQuestion.enablePlain = false;   
                resultQuestion.disableOption = true,          
                resultQuestion.required = details[i].required;
                resultQuestion.hasOther = details[i].hasOther;                
                resultQuestion.isOpen = false;  
                addAnotherQuestion2.push(resultQuestion);                                  
              }
             this.addAnotherQuestion.push(addAnotherQuestion2);
```

Comment: Your array is not reactive that's why, you will need to call $forceUpdate if you change a property of an object inside an array

Comment: @Lk77 the question title gets changed as shown in the image. But options are not updating.

Comment: You could try to wrap your array with reactive function from vue and see if it works

Comment: @Lk77, can you please write some code.

Comment: Well you import reactive from vue and instead of addAnotherQuestion: [...] you do addAnotherQuestion: reactive([...])

Answer (score 0):

Your code shows you're not using `result` from `this.GET_SURVEY_QUESTION()` to update anything.  By the way, I don't have enough SO reputation to add comments to address the other commenter, but your array is reactive. [Modifying array items or object properties are both reactive operations](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats). If you were **adding** or **removing** items/properties then it would not be reactive but I don't see you doing that here (setting an entirely new array is fine).

Comment: I have used getter. As you can see this.questionList. I am receiving the proper response and it is not the problem. I even tried creating new Object and pushing it to this.addAnotherQuestion.push(newly created object based on the keys of default value). but that to not working as expected.

Comment: I have updated the question with another way I tried. But still no success. Do you have any another way How it can be achieved.